# OnClientClick does not work with asp.net and vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I try to create a dynamic web solution with ASP.NET and VB.

My webpage looks like this:

```
<div id="menu" style="position:relative;text-align:center">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg1" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg2" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg3" />
        <br />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg4" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg5" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg6" />
        <br />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg7" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg8" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="PHimg9" />
</div>
```

The VB part like this:

```
Public Class index
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Load_Main()
End Sub

Protected Sub Load_Main()
    Dim img1 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img2 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img3 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img4 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img5 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img6 As New ImageButton()

    img1.ImageUrl = "./resources/EssenTrinken.png"
    img1.OnClientClick = "Load_Eating()"

    img2.ImageUrl = "./resources/Einkaufen2-black.png"
    img3.ImageUrl = "./resources/Special-black.png"
    img4.ImageUrl = "./resources/KosmetikWellness.png"
    img5.ImageUrl = "./resources/KulturGeschichte.png"
    img6.ImageUrl = "./resources/Unterhaltung2-black.png"

    PHimg1.Controls.Add(img1)
    PHimg2.Controls.Add(img2)

    PHimg4.Controls.Add(img3)
    PHimg5.Controls.Add(img4)

    PHimg7.Controls.Add(img5)
    PHimg8.Controls.Add(img6)
End Sub

Protected Sub Load_Eating()
    Dim img1 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img2 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img3 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img4 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img5 As New ImageButton()
    Dim img6 As New ImageButton()

    img1.ImageUrl = "./resources/zurueck.png"
    img2.ImageUrl = "./resources/Bars2.png"
    img3.ImageUrl = "./resources/Cafe.png"
    img4.ImageUrl = "./resources/FastFood2.png"
    img5.ImageUrl = "./resources/Restaurant.png"
    img6.ImageUrl = "./resources/Baeckerei.png"

    PHimg1.Controls.Add(img1)
    PHimg2.Controls.Add(img2)

    PHimg3.Controls.Add(img3)
    PHimg4.Controls.Add(img4)

    PHimg5.Controls.Add(img5)
    PHimg6.Controls.Add(img6)
End Sub

End Class
```

I want that if I click on one of the imagebutton the hole appereance of the frontpage dynamicly changes without loading the hole page new. So I defined several PlacHolder for that.

If I run the webapp but the functionality is not working if I hit the button.

I checked the source and found this tag:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl03" src="./resources/EssenTrinken.png" onclick="Load_Eating();" />
```

What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: What is your JavaScript code for `Load_Eating()`?

Comment: There is no javascript code. I want to use the vb.net code which is defined. Isn't it a legit way?

Comment: `OnClientClick` is for JavaScript. `Click` is for vb.net

Comment: @MikeSmithDev nice catch. this is your answer

Comment: I cant use Click in the vb script. It says that it is a event. So I have to solve my problem with javascript?

Comment: No. How you do it is up to you. I added code to how you do using the `Click` event with postback so you can solve with code behind. If you want to do it with JavaScript... then you are currently on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do this from the code behind, then you need to add the Click event handler:

```
Protected Sub Load_Main()
    Dim img1 As New ImageButton()    
    AddHandler img1.Click, AddressOf Img1Click
    'rest of your code
```

and then have some function that does what you want:

```
Private Sub Img1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    'some code
End Sub
```

Note, this will cause a postback. It is confusing on how you expect to dynamically change the front page without reloading the page and without using JavaScript...

Comment: Thanks to you this solves my problem. But is this setup than really works client sided or are every vb interactions server sided?

Comment: I think as I commented here it unselected it automaticly. I will select it dont worry :D

Answer (score 1):

Add to your Page_load a check for [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

```
if Not IsPostBack Then
   Load_main()
End If
```

This will prevent your page_load method to recreate every button and resetting the value for the Image_click event